# Gaining access to class members from template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, specialization

So, I basically want to "add" extra stuff to the class, depending on what template arguments its being used with and then aliasing it for nicer interface. Something like this:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct basic_foo
{
    T data[N];
};

//what you see as comments is what i tried
template<> //template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct basic_foo<double, 3> //: public basic_foo<T, N>
{
    void foo_fun() 
    {
        std::cout << "I'm a foo function!"; 
        for (auto i : data) std::cout << i << " ";
    }
};

template<> //template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct basic_foo<int, 2> //: public basic_foo<T, N>
{
    void bar_fun() 
    {
        std::cout << "I'm a bar function!";
        for (auto i : data) std::cout << i << " ";
    }
};

using foo = basic_foo<double, 3>;
using bar = basic_foo<int, 2>;

int main()
{   
    foo a = { 12.0, 2.4, 3.0 };
    bar b = { 1, 2 };
}
```

The problem is that I can't access `data` in the specializations.

Is there a way to do this? Or should I rethink my structural decisions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code, as it is now does not compile, because you don't have `data` member in your specializations. You have tried to inherit it from the primary template, and you almost got it.

Make a `basic_foo_base` class (or `struct`) template, where you store `data` and functions that needn't be specialized:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct basic_foo_base
{
    T data[N];
};
```

That was just adding `_base` to the name of the existing definition. Now, define `basic_foo` again:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct basic_foo : basic_foo_base<T, N>
{
};
```

And this is how a specialization will look:

```
template <>
// instantiate the base with the same template arguments
struct basic_foo<double, 3> : public basic_foo_base<double, 3>
{
};
```

I hope I got everything right.

**Edit:** No, I didn't.

Because of inheritance, `basic_foo` won't be an aggregate anymore. We'll need to add some code, so the initialization:

```
foo a = { 12.0, 2.4, 3.0 };
```

is valid again. That is, defining an implicit constructor taking `std::initializer_list`:

```
basic_foo_base(std::initializer_list<T> const& il)
{
    std::copy(il.begin(), il.end(), std::begin(data));
}
```

And adding

```
using basic_foo_base::basic_foo_base;
// or, for the primary template:
using basic_foo_base<T, N>::basic_foo_base;
```

in all `basic_foo`s to include that constructor to the overload resolution.

[**Working code**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad2980d15420ce11)

Comment: The (minor) issue is that `basic_foo` [won't be an aggregate anymore](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19846819/3093378), so you'd need to provide constructors and `using` them in the derived classes.

Comment: @vsoftco Oh, of course. But, I don't know what should the constructors take at this point... `std::initializer_list`?

Comment: Probably. I was just ready to post my solution when you wrote yours (which is basically the same, so I upvoted yours) ;) And in mine I used `std::initializer_lists` http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b353a91521bf267

Comment: Ah, sorry for the late reply. The std::initialializer_list was irrelevant, since in my original code I use a parameter pack, which I expand in the constructor. You solved my problem the second you posted. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to common base class which contain `data`, you may fully specialize:

```
template<>
struct basic_foo<double, 3>
{
    double data[3]; // Should be here.

    void foo_fun() 
    {
        std::cout << "I'm a foo function!"; 
        for (auto i : data) std::cout << i << " ";
    }
};
```