# Why is this array not initializing correctly?

Tags: c, arrays

I have tried putting brackets everywhere I know to, but i keep getting the error "missing braces around initializer". This is an array of struct Point

```
Point pointArray[9][2]={1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,0,0,1,-1,0,0,-1,0,5,1000,1};
```

I have put brackets around each set of points and 2 on each end, and it doesn't change anything

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit the question and supply the definition of 'Point'.

Comment: Could you also supply which compiler you're using?

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
Point pointArray[9][2]={{1,1},{-1,1},{-1,-1},{1,-1},{1,0},{0,1},{-1,0},{0,-1},{0,5},{1000,1}};
```

The way you've done it, is like initialising a one-dimensial array array of 20 elements (`Point pointArray[20]=...;`).

However, that only half solves your problem, since you have **10** pairs in there, and you've specified **9**. You would either have to delete an array entry, or change the definition to `Point pointArray[10][2]=...;`.

Comment: That did not solve the problem, I got the same error

Comment: @user3704616 Do you get the same error? Or something else? Did you take into account last paragraph?

Comment: logic is correct., but you have values for an array[10][2], as there are 10 row elements.

Comment: @nikhil I know. I specified that exact problem, plus 2 possible solutions, in the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: @AntonH ... sorry,  i didnt read your answer completely.. my bad. i just wanned to help get it straight

Comment: @nikhil No problem. Happens to me all the time :)

Comment: You can initialize multidimentional arrays in only one pair of brackets like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157251/multidimensional-array-initialization-in-c

Answer (score 2):

If you have a structure type like:

```
typedef struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
} Point;
```

then the fully braced version of the initializer should be:

```
Point pointArray[9][2] =
{
    { {  1,  1 }, { -1,  1 } },
    { { -1, -1 }, {  1, -1 } },
    { {  1,  0 }, {  0,  1 } },
    { { -1,  0 }, {  0, -1 } },
    { {  0,  5 }, { 1000, 1 } },
    // 4 uninitialized rows in the array - populated with zeros
};
```

The innermost sets of braces surround the structures; the middle sets of braces surround pairs of structures, corresponding to entries in the `[2]` dimension of the array.  The outermost braces surround 5 of the possible 9 initializers for the first dimension `[9]` of the array.