# Does C fill the remainder of a multidementional array with 0?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, initialization, language-lawyer

In a Korean government examination, (1) was a correct statement.

```
Choose the wrong statement for the following two-dimensional array in C:
int mat[3][4]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
(1) The value of mat[2][2] is 0.
```

I had been thinking that C does not fill integer arrays with 0's, so I tried to look up the specification, but document was too big. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18157278/455796) (screenshot below for quick viewing, full text is in the link) seems to be saying that incomplete initialisation is implied to be 0, but is it guaranteed by the C specification?

[image]

Comment: initializing at least one member of an aggregate guarantees all will be initialized. (There used to be an exception for string literals)

Comment: Re "*I had been thinking that C does not fill integer arrays with 0's*", That's the case for non-static arrays without an initializer.

Comment: All the answers have misinterpreted the question. It does not ask about multidimensional arrays but about multidementional arrays. When the arrays are demented in multiple ways, there is no guarantee of conformance to the C standard, so the value is unknown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization):

> 19 The initialization shall occur in initializer list order, each
> initializer provided for a particular subobject overriding any
> previously listed initializer for the same subobject; **all subobjects
> that are not initialized explicitly shall be initialized implicitly
> the same as objects that have static storage duration**.

and

> 10 If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized
> explicitly, its value is indeterminate. **If an object that has static
> or thread storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then**:
>
> — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
>
> **— if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or
> unsigned) zero;**
>
> — if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively)
> according to these rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
>
> — if it is a union, the first named member is initialized
> (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is initialized
> to zero bits;

So all elements of the array `mat` that are not initialized explicitly are initialized implicitly by zeroes.

```
int mat[3][4]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

As a result in the above declaration `mat[2][2]` is equal to `0`.

Have I passed the Korean government examination?:)

Comment: Additionally, the C initialization rules have these weird but well-defined rules regarding initializing everything in sequence based on a "current object", allowing sloppy syntax like `int mat[3][4]={1,2,3,4,5,6};` in the first place. And guaranteeing that it is equivalent to `int mat[3][4]={ {1,2,3,4},{5,6,0,0} ... };`

Answer (score 2):

Initialization is either none or all.  No partial.  For integer types its 0 for the rest.

Answer (score 1):

One of the basic mottos of the C language is that "you don't get what you didn't pay for". In accordance with this principle, C generally does not initialize anything that you did not explicitly initialize.

However:

When you do initialize something, and specifically an array, C will thoroughly initialize that array. C allows you to specify only part of the elements to initialize the array with, but this does not mean that C will only initialize those elements, and leave the rest uninitialized. C will initialize the entire array, and any elements you did not explicitly initialize will receive their default value, which, in the case of integers, is zero.